# ReadProcessMemory WriteProcessMemory iOS

Tags: ios, jailbreak, readprocessmemory

Is it possible to manage the memory of a process alien to itself in iOS?

By this I mean to be able to read and write bytes on iOS applications, something like ReadProcessMemory and WriteProcessMemory functions of Windows.

I know I have to program in Objective-C, but I do not know if these functions exist in it, or if iOS has them in its libraries. Or something similar to them.

Any hints?

Comment: I'm going to tag this with [jailbreak] so that answers will be encouraged to focus on a technical solution rather than rejection from the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

This will absolutely get your rejected from the app store, so there is no reason for them to exist in objective-c.  If you don't need to submit the app to the app store, you will need to look into unix tools and a possible jail breaking requirement.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to know it, just to develop an game hacking application (like the Cheat Engine on Windows), obviously I'm not interested in publish it in the App Store, just wanted to know if it was possible or not. Thanks anyways.

Comment: In that case, if you can do it using a command line app written in C on OS X, then you can likely reproduce that effect on iOS.  I'm not sure if a non-jailbroken iOS environment will allow this behavior or not though.  If a certain command line tool that you need doesn't exist on iOS you will need to jailbreak and install it.

Comment: Given that jailbreaking involves gaining root access to the device, and that a debugger can run on the device and attach to another process, this is most definitely possible. The only question is "how?", and unfortunately I don't know the answer. @Screitor

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks anyways, I'm gonna try another ways.